# Django Combine Window Functions with Standard annotations

Tags: python, mysql, django

I have a Django Model I'm trying to implement a Windows Function and a standard Annotation on.
Ideally I want to return a ranking of rows and get an aggregation of another column in the same queryset.

As an example mapped below:

```
queryset = ProductData.objects.values('date','sku)
.annotate(row_number=ExpressionWrapper(Window(expression=RowNumber(),
                                              partition_by=[F('sku')],
                                              order_by=F('date').asc()),
                                              output_field=FloatField()))
.annotate(units_sold=ExpressionWrapper(Sum(F('units_sold')), output_field=FloatField()))
.order_by('date','sku')
```

The resulting posted query is:

**SELECT `product_data`.`SKU`,
DATE_FORMAT(`product_data`.`date`, '%Y-%m-%d') AS `date`,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY `product_data`.`SKU` ORDER BY `product_data`.`DATE` ASC) AS `row_number`,
SUM(`product_data`.`Units_Sold`) AS `Units_Sold`
FROM `product_data`
GROUP BY `product_data`.`SKU`, DATE_FORMAT(`product_data`.`date`, '%Y-%m-%d'),
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY `product_data`.`SKU` ORDER BY `product_data`.`DATE` ASC)
ORDER BY `date` ASC, `product_data`.`SKU` ASC**
**

When running this method I get the following error:
*Error Code: 3593. You cannot use the window function 'row_number' in this context.'*

The query needs to be:

**SELECT `product_data`.`SKU`,
DATE_FORMAT(`product_data`.`date`, '%Y-%m-%d') AS `date`,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY `product_data`.`SKU` ORDER BY `product_data`.`DATE` ASC) AS `row_number`,
SUM(`product_data`.`Units_Sold`) AS `Units_Sold`
FROM `product_data`
GROUP BY `product_data`.`SKU`, DATE_FORMAT(`product_data`.`date`, '%Y-%m-%d')
ORDER BY `date` ASC, `product_data`.`SKU` ASC**

The problem is that the first annotation defined by the Windows Function creates a new "value Column".
So in django by defualt when I call the second annotation it performs a group by on all the **Value** fields. In django context the group by is then **[sku, date, row_number]**.
I need to establish the group by to only work off of the provided values and not include the Windows Function.

**The results should look like this:**

| SKU | Date | row_number | units_sold |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| SKU-A | 2020-04-01 | 1 | 0 |
| SKU-A | 2020-04-02 | 2 | 1 |
| SKU-A | 2020-04-03 | 3 | 1 |
| SKU-A | 2020-04-04 | 4 | 1 |
| SKU-A | 2020-04-05 | 5 | 2 |
| SKU-A | 2020-04-06 | 6 | 4 |
| SKU-A | 2020-04-07 | 7 | 3 |

I've seen a similar issue on this thread:
[Django Window annotation using combined with distinct clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61217662/django-window-annotation-using-combined-with-distinct-clause)

But no specific solution.

Below Django's documentation on Window Functions:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/expressions/#window-functions